# Quartz Scheduler jobs dont work same times. Allsways work only one

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, quartz.net

Problem: My jobs doesn't work same times. Allways work only one. What is wrong in code.

**Programs runs like below:**
[image]

**Expected runs**

**info: exampleProject.Api.Services.QuartzServices.Job1[0]
Job1 is working...

info: exampleProject.Api.Services.QuartzServices.Job2[0]
Job2 is working...**

**CustomQuartzHostedService**

```
public class CustomQuartzHostedService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory;
        private readonly IJobFactory jobFactory;
        private readonly JobMetadata jobMetadata;
        public CustomQuartzHostedService(ISchedulerFactory
            schedulerFactory,
            JobMetadata jobMetadata,
            IJobFactory jobFactory)
        {
            this.schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
            this.jobMetadata = jobMetadata;
            this.jobFactory = jobFactory;
        }
        public IScheduler Scheduler { get; set; }
        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
            Scheduler.JobFactory = jobFactory;
            var job = CreateJob(jobMetadata);
            var trigger = CreateTrigger(jobMetadata);
            await Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger, cancellationToken);
            await Scheduler.Start(cancellationToken);
        }
        public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await Scheduler?.Shutdown(cancellationToken);
        }
        private ITrigger CreateTrigger(JobMetadata jobMetadata)
        {
            return TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity(jobMetadata.JobId.ToString())
            .WithCronSchedule(jobMetadata.CronExpression)
            .WithDescription($"{jobMetadata.JobName}")
            .Build();
        }
        private IJobDetail CreateJob(JobMetadata jobMetadata)
        {
            return JobBuilder
            .Create(jobMetadata.JobType)
            .WithIdentity(jobMetadata.JobId.ToString())
            .WithDescription($"{jobMetadata.JobName}")
            .Build();
        }
    }
```

**CustomQuartzJobFactory**

```
public class CustomQuartzJobFactory : IJobFactory
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        public CustomQuartzJobFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }
        public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle triggerFiredBundle,
        IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            var jobDetail = triggerFiredBundle.JobDetail;
            return (IJob)_serviceProvider.GetService(jobDetail.JobType);
        }
        public void ReturnJob(IJob job) { }
    }
```

**JobMetadata**

```
public class JobMetadata
    {
        public Guid JobId { get; set; }
        public Type JobType { get; }
        public string JobName { get; }
        public string CronExpression { get; }
        public JobMetadata(Guid Id, Type jobType, string jobName,
        string cronExpression)
        {
            JobId = Id;
            JobType = jobType;
            JobName = jobName;
            CronExpression = cronExpression;
        }
    }
```

**Job1**

```
   [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    public class Job1 : IJob
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Job1> _logger;
        public Job1(ILogger<Job1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Job1 is working...");
        }
    }
```

**Job2**

```
 [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    public class Job2 : IJob
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Job2> _logger;
        public Job2(ILogger<Job2> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Job2 is working...");
        }
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
    services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, CustomQuartzJobFactory>();
    services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
    services.AddSingleton<Job1>();
    services.AddSingleton<Job2>();

    services.AddSingleton(new JobMetadata(Guid.NewGuid(), typeof(Job1), "Job1 Defination", "0/10 * * ? * * *")); //Every 10 seconds
    services.AddSingleton(new JobMetadata(Guid.NewGuid(), typeof(Job2), "Job2 Defination", "0/10 * * ? * * *")); //Every 10 seconds

    services.AddHostedService<CustomQuartzHostedService>();
```

Comment: At least you shouldn't make your jobs singletons. Have your considered using the official [MS IoC support](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html) and [the hosted service package](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/hosted-services-integration.html)? They help you out to get the configuration right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working demo：

Change JobMetadata jobMetadata to List in `CustomQuartzHostedService`:

```
public class CustomQuartzHostedService: IHostedService
    {
        private readonly ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory;
        private readonly IJobFactory jobFactory;
        private readonly List<JobMetadata> jobMetadatas;
        public CustomQuartzHostedService(ISchedulerFactory
            schedulerFactory,
            List<JobMetadata> jobMetadatas,
            IJobFactory jobFactory)
        {
            this.schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
            this.jobMetadatas = jobMetadatas;
            this.jobFactory = jobFactory;
        }
        public IScheduler Scheduler { get; set; }
        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
            Scheduler.JobFactory = jobFactory;
            foreach (var j in jobMetadatas) {
                var job = CreateJob(j);
                var trigger = CreateTrigger(j);
                await Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger, cancellationToken);
            }
            await Scheduler.Start(cancellationToken);
        }
        public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await Scheduler?.Shutdown(cancellationToken);
        }
        private ITrigger CreateTrigger(JobMetadata jobMetadata)
        {
            return TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity(jobMetadata.JobId.ToString())
            .WithCronSchedule(jobMetadata.CronExpression)
            .WithDescription($"{jobMetadata.JobName}")
            .Build();
        }
        private IJobDetail CreateJob(JobMetadata jobMetadata)
        {
            return JobBuilder
            .Create(jobMetadata.JobType)
            .WithIdentity(jobMetadata.JobId.ToString())
            .WithDescription($"{jobMetadata.JobName}")
            .Build();
        }
    }
```

Add `List<JobMetadata>` in startup(I test with every 3 second):

```
            JobMetadata j1 = new JobMetadata(Guid.NewGuid(), typeof(Job1), "Job1 Defination", "0/3 * * ? * * *");//Every 3 seconds
            JobMetadata j2 = new JobMetadata(Guid.NewGuid(), typeof(Job2), "Job2 Defination", "0/3 * * ? * * *");//Every 3 seconds
            services.AddSingleton(new List<JobMetadata> { j1,j2});
```

result:
[image]